# PHP posting error

Tags: php, html

I keep getting a Cannot POST /app/newpost/newpost.php error when i try to post a HTML form and retrieve the data from another HTML page

HTML for the form is:

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1 style="font-size:36px; font-family:verdana;">
    Create a new forum post
  </h1>
</div>
<form action="newpost.php" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
 <P style="font-size:24px; font-family:verdana;">Title: <input type="text" name="title" style="font-size:24px; font-family:verdana;"></P>
 <P style="font-size:24px; font-family:verdana;">Description: <input type="text" name="desc" style="font-size:24px; font-family:verdana;"></P>
<input type="submit" action="window.location.href='/app/forum/forum.component.html'" style="background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 15px 32px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; font-size: 16px; margin: 4px 2px; cursor: pointer;">
</form>
```

PHP file is

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{$title = $_POST['title'];
$desc = $_POST['desc']
}
?>
```

im still very new to PHP someone pls help! 
And how to retrieve the posted data on another html page?

Comment: Edit your question to include the full error message you get. Also include your full source code as well.

Comment: You have to add input name attribute for retrieving post data.

Comment: Cannot POST /app/newpost/newpost.php

Comment: this is the full error on my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a web server with PHP installed to test/run your PHP script. You cannot have it run from your file system directory. Depending on your environment you might want to installed something called WAMP, XAMP or MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there ; missing

i have changed you code to bellow, it should run now

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $desc = $_POST['desc'];
}
?>
```

try this

Comment: try to run the script locally by using WAMP/MAMP or apache server

Answer (score 0):

I think having `action="newpost.php"` as an attribute in the `form` tag and `action="window.location.href='/app/forum/forum.component.html'"` as an attribute in the `input type="submit"` tag is a contradiction. You might want to try to erase one of them.